# Storing lvalue reference to a dynamically allocated array

Tags: c++

Consider following class of custom array

```
template <typename element, unsigned int size>
class array
{
private:
    element (&data)[size];
public:
    array(element (&reference)[size]):data(reference){}
    array():data(new element [size]){} // This is where my problem arises
};
```

Obviously, in initialization list of constructor evaluates the rvalue expression (the *new-expression*) to ***rvalue of pointer instead of reference type***. So in MSVC (Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 RC) prompts the error about type conversion from ***element **** to ***element (&)[size]***.

However, I think that if I can perhaps convert the rvalue from pointer to reference, it should compile. Is there any chance I can make it there in initialization list of constructor? Or perhaps it just all conflicts with the principle of C++ language? I've investiaged into **reinterpret_cast**, but the only rule I find relevant is

> "An ***lvalue expression*** of type T1 can be converted to reference to
>   another type T2. The result is an lvalue or xvalue referring to the
>   same object as the original lvalue, but with a different type." - cppreference.com

which clearly states that the conversion applies to ***lvalue expression***.

OK, I know what you might think now - why do you need such class of custom array and why don't you just composite pointer instead of the problemtic reference? Well...you always need different approaches to choose before knowning the best don't you?

Comment: Let's imagine you could somehow cast the result of `new` to fit your use case. How would you ever be able to delete that correctly?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with rvalue references, and there's nothing specific to C++11 either that I can see.

Comment: @Mat You got the point ;D. Actually, there is one flag in the class, indicating if data is a reference that wraps or not. If it wraps, it doesn't delete. Otherwise it does. It didn't come up with the class I posted here for convenience.

Comment: @Yang: That is an anti-pattern. You should redesign so that the class does a task and need not care whether the memory is to be released or not.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas There is one circumstance this pattern is useful. Supposing invention of dynamic or weak typed language based on C++ and user is not expected to new or delete upon declaring variable of this array type, memory allocation must be managed upon construction.

Nevertheless, of course I wouldn't make use of it in serious job :-).

Comment: @Yang: The problem is not managing the resource internally, which is fine, but having a class that can either manage or not the resource and has to keep track of it. Management of the resource should be the single responsibility of a class. In this case I could think of `shared_ptr`. Always pass the `shared_ptr` to the constructor and the caller can decide whether to allocate with `new` or use a stack allocated block (in which case they can construct a `shared_ptr` with a no-op deleter. Also, if the class is to ever manage memory, it would be clearer to store a pointer than a reference.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Personally, I hate shared_ptr for no reason. If it has to be pointer, I'd definitely choose pure C instead of C++ to fulfill as both are turing complete ;-) and pointer is much easier to manipulate. Actually, except for type safty, I can't convince myself to use reference or even C++ either. I believe that logics helps suckers to understand computer, not smarters to make it work. If I can type fast enough to program same efficiently as assembly coders, I would certainly do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's this about C++11 and rvalue references? To get a lvalue expression to the value pointed to by a pointer, just use the unary `*` operator. It's been part of the language since the beginning. All you have to do here is make sure you get a pointer to an array, rather than a pointer to the first element of the array.

```
template <typename element, unsigned int size>
class array
{
private:
    element (&data)[size];
public:
    array() : data(*new element[1][size]) { }
    array(element (&reference)[size]) : data(reference) { }
};
```

As mentioned by Mat in his comment, the parameterless constructor here is a very bad idea, because the memory will not be freed. Hopefully, having a working code sample will allow you to experiment a bit and come to the same conclusion.

Comment: hmm...somebody else did I guess.

Comment: Who will delete the memory and why my solution is not good compared to this?

Answer (score 0):

You are not at all using R-Value references in this code. There is not a single usage of `&&` r-value symbol.

**EDIT:**

```
template <typename element, unsigned int size> 
class array 
{ 
private: 
    element (&data)[size]; 
    static element DefaultArrRef[size];
public: 
    //array(element (&reference)[size]):data(reference){} 
    array():data(DefaultArrRef){}
}; 


template <typename element, unsigned int size> 
element array<element,size>::DefaultArrRef[size];
```

Comment: You're defining `data` as an array, rather than as a reference to an array. That's a good idea, but significantly different from what's asked.

Comment: You mean this: `int (&ref_array)[10];` - Which is not possible.

Comment: That's perfectly valid, and exactly what's in the question.

Comment: @Ajay hvd tells exactly. What the class contains is a reference, not array itself.

Comment: This is still completely different than the code in the question. In this approach, all instances of `array` for which the default constructor is called will *share* the same array, while in the code in the question each instance holds it's own separate data.